# Visual Studio 2019: Strange behavior using property sheets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I wish I could provide a better description, but this is hard to describe succinctly.

Let me start with some background. This is a C++ solution using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. It has 12 projects of different types (DLLs, static libraries, and executable tests) and 4 build configurations ((Release, Debug)x(Win32, x64)). Keeping all the properties the same across projects and configurations has been a massive pain, so I decided to try using property sheets so that I could have the properties shared across projects. Given the structure of my solution, the property sheets are themselves somewhat complicated, but it's an improvement over what I had.

However about halfway through this migration I noticed some odd behavior. When I inspect the properties for one of my projects (a static library), the properties page is almost totally empty. Not only the properties I have changed with my sheets are missing, but even the default properties that you would expect.

However when I build this project, I can tell that most of the custom properties are in fact set correctly despite being missing, so it would seem like a UI bug, except some properties are not set correctly, for example the build log is not written to the correct location despite being set in the property sheet. This makes me worried that other more important properties may not be set correctly as well, but it's hard to know which properties are getting set and which are not.

I have another static library project that is set up in the same way with the same property sheets, and it behaves normally. It shows the expected properties in the project properties, and the build log is even in the correct location.

It gets even stranger. When I run the build from the command line using `msbuild` or `devenv`, the build log is written to the correct location. This suggests that building from the command line is working correctly, and that building from Visual Studio is not the same as building from the command line.

I ran `msbuild -pp` to see the expanded project file, and it looks correct. I diffed this project file with another static library from my solution that is working normally, and the diff is as expected, only the project names, paths, and source files are different. I did this diff on the expanded projects files too and they were the same except the expected differences.

I have closed and reopened Visual Studio countless times. I have also unloaded and reloaded the project. I have even tried deleting the .vs folder. None of these had any affect.

[Here is a link to my code.](https://sourceforge.net/p/kered13-notepad-plugins/code/ci/Property%20Sheets/tree/)

[Screenshots demonstrating what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt5AS.jpg)

Is there any way to fix this? Have I done something wrong? I would like all of the properties from my property sheets to show up in the project properties, and I especially need all of them to apply when building the project.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `<ItemGroup>`s containing the source files below the `<ImportGroup>`s in my project file (`.vcxproj`) fixed the problem. I cannot explain *why* this works, or why this was ever a problem in the first place, but it fixed it.